# Decrease font size in Word 2010 character style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

Is it possible to define a character style that builds on **Default Paragraph Font** and set its font' size to be 1 point less than the one used by the paragraph?

I tried putting **-1** into the font size but Word complained that value can be anywhere between 1 and 1638.

#### Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not. In Word, you can set font size in points, and that’s it. The best you can do is to document your styles as you set them up, so that it will be easier to modify them if it turns out that e.g. the basic (Normal) font size must be changed.